# Исключение NullPointerException

Tags: java, исключения

как я понимаю данное исключение говорит о том, что объект не хранит в себе данные, и поэтому при выводе на экран информации, выдает исключение, но я вроде как записываю в переменную значение, и данное исключение не должно появляться, рассудите пожалуйста, тут два класса с наследованием

```
public class Main extends Field {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Field().initMap();
        new Field().printMap();
    }
}
```

второй класс

```
public class Field  {
    protected final int SIZE = 3;
    protected char[][] map;
    protected final char DOT_EMPTY = '*';

    protected void initMap(){
        map = new char[SIZE][SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < SIZE; j++ ){
                map[i][j] = DOT_EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void printMap(){
        for(int i = 0; i<= SIZE; i++){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i =0; i <SIZE; i++){
            System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
            for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
                System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

жалуется на строку кода `System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");` в классе Field

Comment: в таком применении вам не нужно наследовать Main от Field. зачем это наследование?

Comment: @pavlofff просто тренируюсь в наследовании

Comment: в таком случае перед тренировкой вам нужно получше понять теорию, смысл наследования и когда именно оно используется, потому что это совершенно неудачный пример тренировки и зачем нужно наследование вы, наверное, не очень понимаете. Вы, к примеру, понимаете, что двумя словами extends Field вы "прицепили" весь класс Field к классу Main,  "тащите" его везде за этим классом мертвым грузом, никак не используя этот прицеп, но расходуя память и процессорное время на его бесполезное присутствие

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас в двух разных объектах происходит действие:

- `new Field().initMap();` – создаете новый объект и в нем заполняется его `map`
- `new Field().printMap();` – создаете новый объект и в нем обращаетесь к его `map`, а она пуста, т.к. `initMap()` не был вызван для него

Правильно так:

```
public class Main extends Field {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field field = new Field();
        field.initMap();
        field.printMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: @VladZherihov, сделайте методы `public`, если метод protected/private, то они не доступны другим классам. Т.е. просто уберите `protected `

Comment: насколько мне известно, public нужно использовать как можно реже, что бы лишнего доступа не было

Comment: @VladZherihov, эти ограничения чисто для программистов и от программистов. При желании можно вызвать и приватный метод. Слышали про рефлексию? :)

Comment: пока нет, так понимаю, что надо услышать)

Answer (score 0):

В начало метода printMap() можете добавить проверку на null:

```
protected void printMap(){
    if(map == null) {
       System.err.println("Map is empty");  //удалить, если вывод ошибки не требуется
       return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```